# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

tengo este error que se disparo en un proyecto en el que estoy trabajando y es la primera vez que me pasa. Cambie mucho la estructura del código que tenía pensando en que podría solucionarlo pero no.

voy a añadir primero el fragmento de códido js donde figura el error y luego el php con el que interactura.

```
$('#base_form').submit(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Ajax/base-list.php',
        type: 'GET',
        _success: function (response) {
            let bases_load = JSON.parse(response); //Linea donde se manifiesta el error en consola.
            let template = '';
            bases_load.forEach(bases_load => {
                template += `
                <tr>
                    <td>${bases_load.nombre}</td>
                    <td>${bases_load.cantidad} </td>
                </tr>
                `;
            });

            $('#detalle_bases').html(template);

            },
            get success() {
                return this._success;
            },
            set success(value) {
                this._success = value;
            },
        });
    
});
```

explicacion del codigo= Se ejecuta con la accion submit del formulario base_form, el url es del php que adjunto a continuación. Elijo el type GET ya que no requiero mandar datos, solo recibir el resultado de una consulta en MySql.

**El error se manifiesta en la linea de "let base_load = JSON.parse(response)".**

El objetivo de la funcion es imprimir los datos que le pido a php en una tabla con dos columnas.

```
<?php
 include('../../conectar.php');

$consulta = "SELECT nombre, COUNT(id_base) AS cantidad FROM produccion_base_temporal GROUP BY id_base";
$ejecucion = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

$json = array();
while($resultado=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecucion)){
    $json[] = array(
        //'id_base' => $resultado['id_base'],
        'nombre' => $resultado['nombre'],
        'cantidad' => $resultado['cantidad']
    );
}

$jsonString = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonString;
```

?>

explicacion del php: Hago un count para saber la cantidad de unidades de un producto y su nombre. Creo la variable $json = array() para guardar los datos que se insertan en dicho array por medio de la repetitiva. Al finalizar, creo una variable para mandar el json_encode y la mando.

No se precisamente que es el error, en unos videos en youtube sale que puede ser algo de comillas, pero esta todo bien. Tengo excactamente el mismo codigo (el js y php) cambiando la tabla unicamente pero con la misma funcionalidad, y anda perfectamente. Ya intente solamente cambiar el nombre del archivo php y el id del tbody pero no funciona.

Comment: Hola!, me salen exactamente los datos que solicito: var_dump: string(173) "[{"nombre":"Blanca","cantidad":"16"},{"nombre":"Marron","cantidad":"1"},{"nombre":"Negra","cantidad":"6"},{"nombre":"Agua","cantidad":"2"},{"nombre":"Limon","cantidad":"3"}]"

Comment: No puedo creer que era eso, lo pude solucionar, muchisimas gracias!!!, lo que no entiendo ahora, es porque funciona en las consultas que son indenticas, pero bueno, mientras funcione...

Answer (score 1):

Comencemos por el hecho de que en el objeto de la petición ajax, debes indicar el tipo de formato en el que vendrá la data de tu backend, con esto:

```
$.ajax({
    ..................
    dataType: 'json'
})
```

Para que de este modo en la petición HTTP se le haga *saber* al servidor el formato en el cual esperamos que llegue la data de dicha solicitud.

Por otro lado a nivel del backend, deberías tener al inicio algo como esto:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Para desde tu backend declarar el formato que la respuesta estará emitiendo hacia la petición de tu frontend.

Como tampoco desde el backend especificas el *MIME*<sup>1</sup> que ofrece la respuesta no *hay modo de que JQuery* pueda determinarlo de forma exacta.

De lo anterior te comparto como luce la información que llega a través de: *Response Headers* cuando analizas la respuesta en la pestaña de: **Network** desde tu navegador web.

Sin especificar en el backend el *Mime* de la respuesta

```
Response Headers
    Connection: close
    Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Date: Sun, 11 Oct 2100 01:29:25 GMT
    Host: localhost:8000
    X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.1
```

Cuando en el backend, específicas el *MIME* a retornar, en este caso a `application/json`

```
Response Headers
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: application/json
    Date: Sun, 11 Oct 2100 01:31:33 GMT
    Host: localhost:8000
    X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.1
```

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup>[MIMETYPE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/MIME_type)
- [Header en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)
- [dataType en JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)
- *Muy extensa pero altamente útil* [Lista de MIME-Types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)